# Will I be able to stay 3 months in Thailand after October 1?

Tags: visas, thailand

[Thailand to Allow Foreign Tourists to Extend Stay as Covid Eases](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-08-19/thailand-to-allow-foreign-tourists-to-extend-stay-as-covid-eases)

I have Israeli citizenship and I get from the article that Thailand will allow me to stay for 45 days on transit visa. If that is the case, how many days will I get if I extend the 45 days inside Thailand in an immigration office? Could I get **45 + 45**?

Will I be able to stay 3 months in Thailand after October 1?

Comment: Transit visa and visa on arrival are different categories of visa. A Transit visa allows a stay not exceeding 30 days, according to
https://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand-visa/thailand-visa-benefits

Comment: @Traveller yes but given the circumstances?...

Comment: If the 45 days visa isn't a "transit visa" than what visa is it?

Comment: Per the article you linked, it’s a visa on arrival.

Comment: 45 days is transit? What?

Comment: @AnishSheela From https://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand-visa/thailand-visa-benefits for a Transit Visa, the allowed stay must not exceed 30 days and may be extended for 7 to 10 days depending on nationality